# change of variable from $dz\,dz^*$ to $d\Re(z) \, d\Im(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve a gaussian integral of the form
$$\int dz\,dz^*\exp(zKz^*)$$
I tried to make a change of variables so that $dz \, dz^*\to d\Re(z) \, d\Im(z)$ with the map given by
$$\Re(z)=\frac{z+z^*}{2}$$
$$\Im(z)=\frac{z-z^*}{2i}$$
But when I try to calculate the Jacobian I get a matrix
$$\frac{\partial(\Re(z), \Im(z))}{\partial(z, z^*)}=\left(
\begin{matrix}
  1/2 & 1/2 \\
  1/2i & -1/2i
 \end{matrix}\right)$$
Whose determinant is -1/2i. But I don't like that because by mapping to $\mathbb{R}^2$ it should give a real area. So what am I doing wrong?

Sorry for the basic question.

Comment: Not sure, to tell the truth, but I notice that everything rights itself if you switch to $d\Re(z) \mathbf{i} d\Im(z)$ instead.

Comment: $dz d\bar z=(dx+ i dy)\wedge(dx- i dy)= 2i dy dx$ so the integral is imaginary as you noted yourself.