# Is an integral in the complex plane an integral over a single number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

A recent [question from Juan Saloman](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309255/change-of-variable-from-dz-dz-to-d-rez-d-imz) reminded me of something that has nagged me for years, and I have never understood and never heard explained.  (or maybe I just don't remember, but anyway ...)  In the complex plane, can an integral of the general form $\int dz f(z)$ over the complex plane be treated as a straightforward 1-D integral if no path in the complex plane is specified?  I have been in classes where the professors seemed to do just that.  But, I mean, $z$ has two independent parts, right?  In other words, it's the complex *plane*, not the complex *line*.  I have seen these kinds of integrals before and sort learned to deal with them in a monkey-see-monkey-do fashion, but never really understood what was going on to my own satisfaction.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the complex plane $\Bbb C$ certain functions $z\mapsto f(z)$ are distinguished as being holomorphic. Any such function comes with a domain $\Omega\subset\Bbb C$, which by definition is an open and connected set. 
Given such an $f$ and a curve
$$\gamma:\ [a,b]\to\Omega, \quad t\mapsto z(t)\tag{1}$$
one can consider the integral
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz:=\int_a^b f\bigl(z(t)\bigr)\ z'(t)\ dt\ ,$$
whose value depends on $f$ as well as on $\gamma$.

When $f$ happens to be the derivative of some other analytic function $F:\ \Omega\to\Bbb C$, as $\ \cos\ $ is the derivative of $\ \sin$, and if $(1)$ is an arbitrary curve in $\Omega$ connecting the point $\gamma(a)=z_1\in\Omega$ with the point $\gamma(b)=z_2\in\Omega$ then
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz= F(z_2)-F(z_1)\ .\tag{2}$$
In order to prove $(2)$ consider  the auxiliary function
$$\phi(t):=F\bigl(z(t)\bigr)\qquad(a\leq t\leq b)$$
and rewrite the formula  $\int_a^b \phi'(t)\ dt=\phi(b)-\phi(a)$ in terms of $f$ and $F$.

In this light the formula $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx=F(b)-F(a)$ from ordinary calculus can  be considered as the special case where $\gamma$ is the directed segment $[a,b]\subset\Bbb C$.

Comment: It should be added that, on a **simply-connected** domain, every holomorphic function has an antiderivative.

Comment: Much obliged.  Just to make sure I understand, any two paths give the same integral as long as the two paths together don't encircle any singularities.  Right?

Comment: @bob.sacamento: Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to integrate over a curve, but if $f(z)$ has an antiderivative, it won't matter *which* curve you integrate over, as long as the curve is contained in an open set on which $f$ has an antiderivative. (Only the endpoints of the curve matter.)