# On the meaning of the complex measure $\int_{\mathbb{C}} d z d \bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

I have a problem to understand the meaning of a *complex* measure; i.e., when someone writes ($i \equiv \sqrt{-1}$)
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} d\mathrm{Re}z \, d\mathrm{Im}z  \equiv \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{dz d\bar{z}}{2i} \quad (\ast)
$$
The lefthand-side will yield a real number (after performing the integration over a real-valued function), while it is not obvious that the righthand-side yields a real number. 
Furthermore, how can one obtain the equivalence relation? Is the factor $\frac{1}{2i}$ the Jacobian of some transformation like
$$
z = \mathrm{Re} z + i \, \mathrm{Im} z ,\\
\bar{z} = \mathrm{Re} z - i \, \mathrm{Im} z ,\\
$$
So, the complex measure $dz d\bar{z}$ does not have the same meaning as a ‘simple’ *complex* integration which in complex calculus (integration over a path in the complex plane).

Please provide an explanation for the complex measure and the equivalence relation ($\ast$) above.

---

<sup>*Notes*</sup>


<sup>1. A similar question is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309255); yet no clear proof or justification is provided.</sup>


<sup>2. An example of the relation appears, for instance, in Altland, A. and B. D. Simons. “Condensed Matter Field Theory” ([2nd ed.](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/651601524), 2010), p. 102:</sup>

[image: Altland, p102]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to  be aware that there are intagration of measures and [integration of differiential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Integration). You cab see the difference when using the Change of variables formula.
For example if $V,W$ are vector spaces of same dimension, $\lambda,\mu$ Lebesgue measures on $V$ and $W$ (or rather a Haar measure), and $f : V \rightarrow W$ smooth and compactely supported, then :
$$\int_{x \in V} d\mu(f(x)) = \int_{x \in V} |\mathrm{Jac}(f(x))| ~ d\lambda(x).$$

In your context it is integration of differential form, and you need the following formula.
If $V,W$ are **oriented** vector spaces **not necessarily of the same dimension**, $f : V \rightarrow W$ smooth, $v$ an invertible differential form on $V$ (i.e. volume form), $w$ a differential form on $W$ of degree $\dim V$ then
$$\int_{x \in V} f^*v~(x) = \int_{x \in V} \mathrm{Jac}(f(x)) ~ v(x),$$
where $\mathrm{Jac}(f(x))$ is the unique number such that $f^*v~(x) = \mathrm{Jac}(f(x)) ~ v(x)$ (recall that $v$ is invertible, and it coincides with the determinant when $V$ and $W$ are of the same dimension).

In your situation $V=\mathbb{C}$, $W = \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$, $f : z=x+iy \mapsto (z,\bar{z})$, $v= dx \wedge dy$, and $w = dz_1 \wedge dz_2$, which yields :
$$\int_{z \in \mathbb{C}} dz \wedge d\bar{z} = \int_{z \in \mathbb{C}} -2i ~ dx \wedge dy.$$

**Note :** $dz$, $d\bar{z}$, $dz.d\bar{z}$ are **not** measures nor complex measures. They are complex differential forms of degree 1 or 2.

Comment: Is there a way to perform an integration with the $dz$ and $d\bar{z}$ forms (i.e. in practice, with a specified function), without switching back to $dx$ and $dy$.

Comment: @knzhou Yes. Choose a paramatrization $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}$ (for example $\phi(x,y) = x+iy$). Then by definition :$\int_\mathbb{C} dz \wedge d\bar{z} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} w(\partial_1\phi(x,y),\partial_2\phi(x,y))~dxdy$, where $w(z_1,z_2) = z_1.\bar{z_2}-z_2.\bar{z_1}$ and the second integral is the Riemann or Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the easiest way to see this (up to a sign that has me confused --- are you sure the order of differentials is right in the formula you quoted) is in terms of differential forms.  With $z=x+iy$ (where $x$ and $y$ are real variables), we have $\bar z=x-iy$ and so
$$
dz\land d\bar z=(dx+i\,dy)\land(dx-i\,dy)=(dx\land dx)+i(dy\land dx)
-i(dx\land dy)-(dy\land dy).
$$
Since the wedge product is skew-symmetric, the first and last terms here vanish, and the other two terms combine to give $-2i\,dx\land dy$.

Comment: I am not sure about the order of the differentials; the books does not state that clearly (with mathematical rigour); lack of rigour is actually the root of this problem!

Comment: What happens to the volume element $d z d \bar{z}$? Does it become a complex volume? If we use the _absolute value_ of the Jacobian (as in a usual change of variables), one does _not_ obtain the $-i$ factor. Does the current relation mean that the ‘orientation’ of the volume is not preserved upon the transformation to $z, \bar{z}$?

Comment: @PhilosophiæNaturalis The product $dz\,d\bar z$ is a purely imaginary multiple of an area element.  I see no reason to use the bsolute value of the Jacobian in this complex context. Nor do I see a reasonable meaning for "orientation" since that refers to the signs of *real* numbers.

Comment: Could you refer me to some pedagogical reference about this kind of complex measure?